# vsftpd not responding to LIST

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-10.04, vsftpd

I've got Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop running as a web server and have just installed vsftpd and set it up to allow ascii_upload_enable and ascii_download_enable and also enabled chroot_local_user, chroot_list_enable and chroot_list_file.

However, I'm having trouble getting a file listing back from the server using FileZilla, this is what happens:

> Status:    Resolving address of server.jonbevan.me.uk
>   Status: Connecting to 80.4.79.179:21...
>   Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>   Response:   220 Welcome to server.jonbevan.me.uk FTP service.
>   Command:    USER jon
>   Response:   331 Please specify the password.
>   Command:    PASS *********
>   Response:   230 Login successful.
>   Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
>   Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
>   Status: Connected
>   Status: Retrieving directory listing...
>   Command:    CWD /home/jon
>   Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
>   Command:    PWD
>   Response:   257 "/home/jon"
>   Command:    TYPE I
>   Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
>   Command:    PASV
>   Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (80,4,79,179,196,13)
>   Command:    LIST
>   Response:   425 Failed to establish connection.
>   Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing

And this happens in CuteFTP:

> COMMAND:>  [7/29/2010 3:23:43 PM] LIST
>           [7/29/2010 3:23:43 PM] 150 Here comes the directory listing.
>   ERROR:>     [7/29/2010 3:24:13 PM] Timeout (30000 ms) occurred on accepting data connection from server.
>           [7/29/2010 3:24:13 PM] 426 Failure writing network stream.
>   ERROR:>     [7/29/2010 3:24:13 PM] Trashed response received.

Any ideas what might be the problem? Apologies if I've missed out any important information.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with Luke404.  Check that your vsftpd.conf has the following entries configured and your firewall allows the pasv_min & pasv_max port ranges (10000 - 100010 is just an example).  Remember to restart the service if changes are made to the conf file.

```
    pasv_enable=YES
    pasv_min_port=10000
    pasv_max_port=10010
    pasv_address=[Public IP address of your server]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using PASV mode so your client will try to connect on a "random" port to the server to transfer data, this includes both file transfers *and* directory listings.

The most probable reason it isn't working is that the PASV TCP connection for data transfer cannot be established, usually for one of these reasons:

- firewall on client side blocking outgoing connections
- firewall on server side blocking incoming connections on high ports
- server behind a NAT with only static ftp ports 21,22 forwarded and no packet inspection to statefully forward higher ports

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem

Solved this, editing config of /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config

in the begining of the file, changed this parameter: **IPTABLES_MODULES**

```
# Load additional iptables modules (nat helpers)
#   Default: -none-
# Space separated list of nat helpers (e.g. 'ip_nat_ftp ip_nat_irc'), which
# are loaded after the firewall rules are applied. Options for the helpers are
# stored in /etc/modprobe.conf.
IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp"
```

After restart iptables, could list the files in FileZilla. Hope it helps.